# Rotina de Processamento Paralelo C#

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, thread, funções, lógica

Gostaria de Iniciar um método de tratamento de dados sempre que receber uma String com o conteúdo START através do evento Transceiver.ReceiveLineEventHandler();  porém esse método terá um tempo de processamento pois haverá timeout entre outros recurso.
 O problema é que enquanto faço esse processamento, não posso parar o programa, pois o evento poderá receber outra string que deve ser processada por outros métodos implementados, além disso sempre haverá um endereço do receptor contido na string, e há casos onde será necessário processar a string recebida pelo mesmo método SendAndWaitForResponse() e utilizar o endereco recebido para destinar os dados, porém este ja pode estar sendo utilizado por um START recebido previamente de outro endereço, alguém pode me ajudar com tal problema ? Alguma luz ?

Consegui utilizar o Método SendAndWaitForResponse() em uma Thread separada, desse modo não paro todo o programa. Porém haverá casos onde preciso executar o Método para tratar outra informação vinda de outro endereco simultaneamente

```
    Transceiver.ReceiveLine += new Transceiver.ReceiveLineEventHandler(ProcessReceived);
    public string address = "";

    void ProcessReceived(string line)
    {   

        string[] dados = line.Split('|');
        address = dados[1];
        if (dados[0] == "RECOVERY"){...}
        if (dados[0] == "COMMANDMODE"){...}
        else if (dados[0] == "START"){
        SendAndWaitForResponse(address,line);
    }

    public void SendAndWaitForResponse(string endereco, string line)
    {
     SendMessage(endereco,line);
         ...
    }
```

Comment: qual a versão do Framework que está utilizando? pode utilizar async/await?

Comment: .Net Framwework 4.5, sim, pode usar Async

Comment: eu nunca tentei fazer um EventHandler assíncrono, mas tente o seguinte.: `async void ProcessReceived(string line)` e `await Task.Run(() => { SendAndWaitForResponse(address,line) });`

Comment: Funcionou corretamente Toby, também nunca havia pensado em criar um EventHandler assíncrono =P

Comment: adicionei uma resposta com a sugestão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma chamada assincronia no EventHandler.:

```
Transceiver.ReceiveLine += new Transceiver.ReceiveLineEventHandler(ProcessReceived);
public string address = "";

async void ProcessReceived(string line)
{   
    string[] dados = line.Split('|');
    address = dados[1];
    if (dados[0] == "RECOVERY"){...}
    if (dados[0] == "COMMANDMODE"){...}
    else if (dados[0] == "START"){
    await Task.Run(() => {
        SendAndWaitForResponse(address,line);
    });
}

public void SendAndWaitForResponse(string endereco, string line)
{
    SendMessage(endereco,line);
    ...
}
```